# FLIR/PySpin eventually only delivers part of the video frame

Tags: python, opencv, video-capture, flir, pyspin

I made a frame in the GUI from the real-time video.

When I turn on the computer and run the program, the entire video appears on the screen. **But after a while, when I run the program, only a part of the video appears on the screen.**

The error codes does not happen..
So I don't know what the problem is.

Like this.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RGEsx.png)

I'm using FLIR camera (Spinnaker SDK), Python 3.8 and Visual Studio Code
(FLIR camera is being used by plugging a cable that looks like a wired Internet line into the computer body. )

The code I wrote:

```
    def __init__(self, video_source=0):
        # open the video source 
         self.cap=EasyPySpin.VideoCapture(video_source)  
         if not self.cap.isOpened():
             raise ValueError("ERROR", video_source)
                    

    def getFrame(self):
        if self.cap.isOpened ():
            isTrue, frame_original = self.cap.read()  
            global frame
            
            if isTrue: 
                frame = cv2.resize(frame_original, dsize=(0,0), fx=0.26, fy=0.26, interpolation=cv2.INTER_AREA)
                # if isTure is true then current frame converted to RGB
                return (isTrue, cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB))
            else:     
                return(isTrue, None) 
           
        else: 
            return (None)              
    
    def __del__(self):  
        if self.cap.isOpened():
            self.cap.release()
```

Is there anything to refer to? If you know the solution, please help me.

Comment: can you show what that looks like?

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz I added a picture to the text. But the picture I added is an example. 
When I run it again, I can see the entire screen this time, but I can't see it right away. The time i can see the screen is only about 2 seconds. 

I think it's hard to bring the camera to the frame.

Comment: reality (*a screenshot*) would be more accurate and more useful than a sketch. your sketch implies that the frame becomes larger. why?

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz Oh, it's my mistake. I edited it.